# How to get a sum array from array

Tags: opencl

I'm a new for new for openCL.

I know how to sum a 1D array. But my question is how to get a sum array from 1 1D array in openCL.

```c
 int a[1000];
 int b[1000];
 ....             //save data to a
 for(int i = 0 ;i < 1000; i ++){
    int sum = 0;
      for(int j = 0 ;j < i; j ++){
        sum += a[j];
      }
      b[i] = sum;
  }
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You can look at the source code for the OpenCL sum function in ArrayFire, which is open source, here:  http://www.arrayfire.com/docs/group__reduce__func__sum.htm

Comment: I think you're talking about a "prefix sum" or "scan". Sorry, no answer for now, but websearches like "prefix sum opencl" will bring some results, maybe this already helps a little.

Comment: Your code is the prefix sum. It's equivalent to `for(int i=0 ; i<1000; j++) { sum += a[j]; b[i] = sum; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned - what you want to do is use inclusive parallel prefix sum.  If you're allowed to use OpenCL 2, [they have a workgroup function for it](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/work_group_reduce.html) - they should have had it in there from the start because of how often it is used - so now we have everybody implementing it themselves, often poorly in one way or another.

See [Parallel Prefix Sum (Scan) with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) for the typical algorithms for teaching this.

At the number you mention really it makes no sense to use multiple compute units meaning you will attack it with a single compute unit - so just repeat the loop twice or so - at 64-256, you'll have the sum of so many elements very quickly.  Building on workgroup functions to get the generic reduction functions for any size is an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score -1):

This is a sequential problem. Expressed in another way

```
b[1] = a[0]
b[2] = b[1] + a[1]
b[3] = b[2] + a[2]
...
b[1000] = b[9999] + a[999]
```

Therefore, having multiple threads wont help you at all.
The most optimal way of doing that is using a single CPU. And not OpenCL/CUDA/OpenMP...

This problem is completely different from a reduction, were every step can be divided in 2 smaller steps that can be run in parallel.

Comment: I think your answer should have addressed the OPs code. His code is trivial to parallelize even if it's inefficient. He does `O(n^2)` reads (actually `(n-1)*n/2` reads) and `n` writes. Whereas your suggestion does only `n` reads. That's clearly better but it's not trivial to parallelize (it can be done with two passes).